# What is the best practice when it comes to deleting a table in the Ruby on Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, rails-migrations

I created a few tables last week and I was told to delete them. The suggested way in which I should do it looks like this:

**Sample table:**

```
class CreateMenuTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :menus do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateSpreeMenuRole < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :menu_roles do |t|
      t.belongs_to :role, class_name: 'Role'
      t.belongs_to :menu, class_name: 'Menu'

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**step 1.** `bin/rake db:rollback STEP=6`

**step 2.** after rolling back I have to comment out those tables then

**step 3.** `bin/rake db:migrate`

Btw we still have multiple tables created after that, that's why we still need to run `migrate`.

Comment: Why don't you just use create a new migration in which you use [`drop_table`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-drop_table) to delete the table you do not need anymore? Rolling back doesn't make sense to me if there a newer tables which You want to keep.

Comment: @spickermann im lost to why did they recommend that. I'm actually thinking of just dropping the tables in one migration. so rolling back is not a good approach?

Comment: Rolling back and only re-run the migration that you would like to keep would delete all data in the newer table. I would argue that is not a good idea...

Comment: I dont know about argue man. I'm just a junior here. but what I know its wrong way of doing it. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

1. Generate a migration to drop these tables `rails g migration DropMenuTable` and `rails g migration DropMenuRolesTable`
2. Drop the Tablet by either

**migration not reversible**

```
class DropMenuTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :menus
  end

  def down
    fail ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

```
class DropMenuRolesTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :menu_roles
  end

  def down
    fail ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

or

**migration is reversible**

```
class DropMenuTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :menues do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

```
class DropMenuRolesTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :menu_roles do |t|
      t.belongs_to :role, class_name: 'Role'
      t.belongs_to :menu, class_name: 'Menu'
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

3. run `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 2):

There will be unsuitable commit if you just comment out migration.

Also you will delete all data in other tables.

So the best practice to drop table via migration like this:

```
class DropMenuTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :menus
  end
end

class DropMenuRolesTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :menu_roles
  end
end
```

Comment: As a note, this is an irreversible migration and the tool may bark about that. When you drop a table there's no way to "un-drop" it.

Answer (score 1):

Migrations allow you to evolve your database schema overtime.

When your app is in development it may seem easy to just rollback the migration and make changes, or even delete it. But you shouldn't do it when you have code deployed to production or is sharing code with another developer. Your database will likely become corrupted and will produce hard to fix bugs.

The best thing you can do to delete a table is to create a new migration and [drop_table](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-drop_table) as suggested by spickermann.